# Django: how to search in two database tables, or how two merge two related classes

Tags: django-models

I am trying to learn the basic techniques of Django and ran into a problem that I cannot solve.

I have a database with two tables that contain information on a person, each having three colums. Table 1 has colums id, education, profession, table 2 has colums id, birthday, birthplace. I want to find all teachers that are born in Chicago.

In SQL, that is simple: SELECT ... FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON ... WHERE ...

In Django, in models.py I can construct a class Table1 with attributes id, education, profession and a class Table2 with attributes id, birthday, birthplace. For solving my problem, I need to construct a class Person with attributes id, education, profession, birthday, birthplace, but I cannot find a way to construct this class from the two tables.

Can someone give me a hint how to do that? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Django needs to know that your two models (represented by the two tables) are connected, so include a foreign key in one of your models:

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()
```

You can then make queries like:

```
Album.objects.filter(artist__last_name='Presley')
```

This query is resolved by a `JOIN`.

Alternatively, you could delete your two old models and create a new model with all the fields you need in one place. Note that if you don't want to lose any data, you'd have to write your own data migration.

Comment: Could you accept/upvote my answer if it was helpful?

Comment: What I understand now of foreign key is that, roughly, it is a column in one table of which the value refers to the items of another table. In my situation I found that for each of the tables that I wanted to link to my main table, I had to construct a foreign key column in the main table. With `SQL JOIN` that is not necessary. So I decided to make a new database.

Comment: When you use `SQL JOIN` you have to provide two columns for the `ON` section, so you still need columns with ids that link the two tables. Yes, you can just create a new model as an alternative, but your model structure should be driven by what's a good logical structure that's scalable as opposed what allows you to write the shortest queries. What you did is clearly a solution though. Hope this helps.

Comment: In my old `MySQ`L database I had a main table and five smaller tables, all with the same primary key `pnr`. Every `pnr` in any of the smaller tables was also in the main table. In `MySQL`, I could query all six tables simultaneously with (`LEFT` or `RIGHT`, I always forget) `JOIN`, the tables combined with the key `pnr`. In Django, I was unable to do the same with foreign keys. Only when I created some new foreign key  columns I got it partially working. With one table, as I have it now, in Django everything is simple and elegant. Many thanks for your kind assistance.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.